# Why function return nil FireBase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

Why ever function return nil?!
I try add DispathQue but I don't understand how it should be right!
Pls Help

```
func storagePutData(uid: String, image: UIImage, compretition: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) -> String {
            var downloadURL: String!
            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
            let uploadDara = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!
            let ref = self.refStorage.child("usersProfileImage/\(uid)/\(imageName).png")

            ref.putData(uploadDara, metadata: nil) { (metaDara, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    compretition(err)
                }
                ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if let err = error {
                        compretition(err)
                    } else {
                        downloadURL = url?.absoluteString
                    }
                })
            }
            return downloadURL
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning `downloadURL` before the asynchronous function within your callee function has finished execution. 
At this point, it will have `nil` value, which is correct.

You'll want to use a completion handler to return `downloadURL` when its ready, like -

```
func storagePutData(uid: String, image: UIImage, success:@escaping (String?)->(), error: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        var downloadURL: String!
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let uploadDara = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!
        let ref = self.refStorage.child("usersProfileImage/\(uid)/\(imageName).png")

        ref.putData(uploadDara, metadata: nil) { (metaDara, error) in
            if let err = error {
                error(err)
            }
            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    error(err)
                } else {
                    downloadURL = url?.absoluteString
                    success(downloadURL)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tnx It work!! But can you help again?!
I try create a singleton class for Firebase and it work!
FirebaseAPI.shared.signUP(name: name, email: email, password: password, image: self.profileImageView.image!) { (error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("error")
                self.showAlert(message: err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("hello")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
When error == nil I have alert, but when error != nil I haven't nothing

Comment: I'm sure if your snippet had typo in it, but can you try with this? - `FirebaseAPI.shared.signUP(name: name, email: email, password: password, image: self.profileImageView.image!) {
            let err = error;
            if (error) {
                print("error"); self.showAlert(message: err.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                print("hello"); self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
            }
        }`

Comment: Ohhh, tnx) I did it))